# Can't use Monaca barcode scanner plugin on Android 7

Tags: android-permissions, barcode-scanner, onsen-ui, monaca

I use barcode scanner plugin on my Monaca app. It works nicely without Android 7 devices. I got this error at Android 7 phones:

[image]

In Enlish: Sorry, the android camera faced a problem. You may need to restart the device.

Comment: Khemry, only premium user can i.port plugin right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monaca BarcodeScanner Plugin can’t be used with Android version 6 or higher and it may also not work with Cordova 6.5 projects for iOS platform.

However, you can import [phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) into your Monaca project. This plugin will work on Android version 6 or higher without any issues. Please test it on custom Debugger or built app.